# What is the term for when someone sends requests repeatedly to a server in order for it to crash?

Tags: security, terminology

When someone sends requests repeatedly to a server in order for it to crash; what's the term for this? I'm looking for a software to test this kind of problem but I can't remember the term,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're probably looking for either of

- [DOS, or denial of service, attack](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Denial_of_service) (brings down a server by overloading it)
- An [IDS, or intrusion detection system](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Intrusion_Detection_System) (detects attempts to break your server)
- Programs such as [Nessus](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Nessus_%28software%29) (tries to find vulnerabilities on to your server)
- Packet sniffers such as [Wireshark](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Wireshark) (listens to your network for traffic)

Answer (score 2):

DDOS or DOS, for (distributed) denial of service.

Answer (score 1):

DoS attack: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denial-of-service_attack.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this could be considered "request flooding".